# How to catch model value in Angular which appended with click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a simple question. But I can't figured it out.

I'm trying to catch value of my model(textbox) which I append with click. If I type manually, I can catch value. But otherwise...

[This is my code](http://jsbin.com/fidamuyuna/4/edit)

Thank you!

Comment: Rather then link to a website like jsbin, SO has the ability to put runnable JavaScript snippets inside the question. I would recommend using that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your logic as below

```
 li.on('click', function(){
   var val = $(this).text();
   $scope.carData.year=val;
   input.val(val);
   $scope.$digest();
});
```

Basically sometimes we have to digest the scope when performing operations on click and other events. Edited the jsbin please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

The AngularJS way to do this is:

In view you should have:

```
<ul ng-repeat="element in list">
  <li ng-click="append(element)" >{{element}}</li>
</ul>
```

And in controller:

```
$scope.list = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015];
$scope.append = function (elementToAdd){
    $scope.carData.year = elementToAdd;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to use drop down selection within AngularJS. For more info, look at the Angular docs for `select` and `ngOptions`

template:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
    <input type="text" ng-model="carData.year" placeholder="enter car year." />
    <br/>
    <br/> 
    <span class="nullable">
         <select ng-options="item for item in years" ng-model="carData.year">
         <option value="">-- choose year --</option>
    </select>
    </span>
    <pre>{{carData}}</pre>
</div>
```

controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('App', []);
myApp.controller('Controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.years = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015];
    $scope.carData = {};
});
```